# Use Nokogiri to wrap a document fragment in a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to use Nokogiri to find an iframe and wrap it in a div with a certain class.

So far I have the following code, but this adds a video-container class to the iframe. I need to wrap the iframe in a div and give that div the video-container class:

```
def clean_html
  frag = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(self.description)
  embeds = frag.css("iframe")
  embeds.add_class("video-container") if embeds.count > 0
  self.description = frag.to_html
end
```

Comment: When asking about code you've written, it *REALLY* helps us make sense of your question if you provide the minimum input data, HTML in this case, and the expected output. Without those we're left to invent data and guess what you want based on your description, and, like a picture, code is worth 1000 words. Please see "[mcve]" which explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def clean_html
  frag = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(self.description)
  embeds = frag.css("iframe")
  embeds.wrap("<div class='video-container'>") if embeds.count > 0
  self.description = frag.to_html
end
```

Didn't realize there was a wrap function that lets you wrap a fragment with some html...*face palm*

Comment: The documentation is at http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html#wrapping_a_nodeset.

Comment: do you know if there's any way of doing this with  erb?